cant encrypt RSAOAEP384 in JAVA with PublicKey
Good day!
I have a working JavaScript script that obtains a token from the server. I need to implement something similar in Java. The essence is that we receive a string from the server in the form of "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY.....", we convert it into an RSAPublicKey and use it to encrypt a password with RSAOAEP384 and send it to the server, but my implementation(with X509EncodedKeySpec) gets a system.error response from the server.
I suspect that everything is because of how I try to convert the string into a PublicKey, the modulus always turns out to be the same number, but it is different from the modulus obtained in the script, the exponent is always 65537 and it is the same both there and here, but as I understand it, this is standard, there may be some peculiarity in converting a string into a publicKey in Java?
working JS:
const pubKey = KEYUTIL.getKey(pubkeyResp.pubKey)
    const encodedPassword = encodeURIComponent(password);
    let encryptedPassword = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < encodedPassword.length / 270; i++) {
        let currntValue = encodedPassword.substr(i * 270, 270);
        let encryptValueCurrent = KJUR.crypto.Cipher.encrypt(currntValue, pubKey, "RSAOAEP384");
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword == "" ? "" : encryptedPassword + "00000001";
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword + hextob64(encryptValueCurrent);
    }

my code in JAVA:
public static RSAPublicKey createRsaPublicKey(String pubKey) {
        PemObject pemObject;
        try (PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pubKey))) {
            pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
        }
        byte[] pemBytes = pemObject.getContent();
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pemBytes);
        return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    }

    public static String encryptPubKeyWithPassword(String pubKey, String password, String version) {
        try {
            String encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = createRsaPublicKey(pubKey);
            StringBuilder encryptedPasswordBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            for (int i = 0; i < encodedPassword.length(); i += 270) {
                String currentValue = encodedPassword.substring(i, Math.min(i + 270, encodedPassword.length()));
                if (encryptedPasswordBuilder.length() > 0) encryptedPasswordBuilder.append("00000001");
encryptedPasswordBuilder.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(currentValue.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
            }
            return encryptedPasswordBuilder + version;
}

pubKey:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\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\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
RSAKey from JS:
RSAKey {
  n: BigInteger {
    '0': 58867183,
    '1': 137037630,
    '2': 145229021,
    '3': 121185575,
    '4': 157098665,
    '5': 249159950,
    '6': 248294190,
    '7': 215876478,
    '8': 98580213,
    '9': 63848600,
    '10': 165282160,
    '11': 131281605,
    '12': 115377866,
    '13': 204781969,
    '14': 265602811,
    '15': 133670915,
    '16': 127614318,
    '17': 84199178,
    '18': 136237668,
    '19': 89287808,
    '20': 41042381,
    '21': 148474285,
    '22': 54706012,
    '23': 223719942,
    '24': 231660269,
    '25': 140863366,
    '26': 188713695,
    '27': 46922831,
    '28': 22365144,
    '29': 85563023,
    '30': 126529902,
    '31': 14324486,
    '32': 224132810,
    '33': 174291986,
    '34': 40882129,
    '35': 102463184,
    '36': 5450829,
    '37': 53645770,
    '38': 98177440,
    '39': 220621137,
    '40': 55851274,
    '41': 96178430,
    '42': 169531095,
    '43': 83223756,
    '44': 159014492,
    '45': 198009744,
    '46': 18128783,
    '47': 253111325,
    '48': 74724496,
    '49': 135835644,
    '50': 137368929,
    '51': 4582185,
    '52': 95869670,
    '53': 38711790,
    '54': 129115200,
    '55': 86760032,
    '56': 163125689,
    '57': 44807888,
    '58': 166436970,
    '59': 141359429,
    '60': 26491471,
    '61': 45949224,
    '62': 185954864,
    '63': 95959219,
    '64': 113443150,
    '65': 104912666,
    '66': 3852589,
    '67': 224808516,
    '68': 227353529,
    '69': 203674566,
    '70': 266317585,
    '71': 184733963,
    '72': 219059731,
    '73': 130954626,
    '74': 7435987,
    '75': 68160374,
    '76': 263211723,
    '77': 213901668,
    '78': 103822858,
    '79': 244541455,
    '80': 72209410,
    '81': 18396637,
    '82': 182549811,
    '83': 79561430,
    '84': 195276964,
    '85': 266248574,
    '86': 249234749,
    '87': 197009176,
    '88': 121965431,
    '89': 178401014,
    '90': 225262278,
    '91': 178824621,
    '92': 49815136,
    '93': 202802284,
    '94': 202874655,
    '95': 212646768,
    '96': 251681821,
    '97': 52336507,
    '98': 265077735,
    '99': 101827201,
    '100': 185796079,
    '101': 63094251,
    '102': 106391510,
    '103': 3363515,
    '104': 241100038,
    '105': 2969662,
    '106': 20711053,
    '107': 154141537,
    '108': 258381146,
    '109': 713517,
    t: 110,
    s: 0
  },
  e: 65537,
  d: null,
  p: null,
  q: null,
  dmp1: null,
  dmq1: null,
  coeff: null,
  isPublic: true,
  isPrivate: false
}

My RSAPublicKey:
2024-04-09T18:08:10.252+03:00  INFO 2876 --- [test-token] [nio-8080-exec-5] c.e.test-token.ClientUtil     : Sun RSA public key, 3072 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 3953226311687758595392111994184029919105572353883850175466519164541873393823923732214781564401042342584241029257336199908139796366497541069327180034755296728788397456817216176094110417813365270437034224139108683316529614756336144052543998303152918929941819677301941145250628636498495113956820927519270970709149908767271627169825801967465740997006710347979917608611090978116377701630380908449017037401297495565187968809576663765854765455615940054260715071874403034550696249783288415681844605115585869191283022766347390049238750984142454221808268833091744962848703466396221134103055688292413446595077216756761727193028024470215530244768050010826877173235699637691655955908473771170645074319262049197935623437229535078523321083906712227132222561047274756830518955068353360103889423586339385295309120615979992652763536784371821993620190106467929309258100886903422590542463117376022420894267089887465438053796937919013636309925359
  public exponent: 65537


You left out the most important debugging detail. What is the system error? Copy and paste it exactly into your question. Regarding "but my implementation(with X509EncodedKeySpec) gets a system.error response from the server".

@GetSet
added response

You said you get a "system.error". Not seeing it.

System error. Please contact administrators.
Ok. I see. Because your credentials fail. Let me examine your code now.

How long is your password that encryption with RSA in chunks is necessary? RSA encryption with chunks is an anti-pattern, slow, exposes vulnerabilities and is error-prone.

You might be getting blocked based on origin. Are you trying to hack into someone else's site or is the server fully under your control?

when credential is wrong in js, server response is 

I ask if this is a hacking attempt because you showed the "system.error" as if it isn't your code that generated the html that accompanies it. Who wrote the code that generated that html? Regarding System error. Please contact administrators..

@Topaco
After encryption, the length of the password is always 520 characters, and it's the same in working script.

Again who wrote the code on the server that produced the "System error. Please contact administrators" and other html? Not you right? You're trying to hack into a site correct?

@GetSet this is serverRespons, i have credentials, i can go to server from browser,  but I have to go there from my application from the backend

@electrovoz You dont go thru the same front-end route for the backend of your application. You use their API if they have one. If you want further help you will have to provide further information. What is this site that you are trying to gain access to?

Your jsrsasign code seems to perform an RSA encryption (in chunks). But your Java code uses JWE, are you not trying to port it 1:1?

i have to get a token and send some requests from back

@Topaco
I tried jwe nimbus and cipher, you can see it in the comments in the code

@Topaco
maybe the modulus is different in java and js?

Again what is the site that you are trying to get into? You are not showing any code in your question that shows an API request regarding "i have to get a token and send some requests from back". Where's your code for this part. I suspect you came here to get help on your hacking attempt (which is okay because you could be an ethical hacker). But not okay because your question lacks too many details, such as real purpose. And likely unethical for that reason.

I tried to redirect the encryption to a js script and the request to receive a token was valid, but for such an implementation then you will have to add another node in the application, but this will affect the performance, is it really impossible to implement the login in java

@GetSet
This is a commercial development, I can't show you the path

@electrovoz I dont need to see the path. Where is the code that performs the API call regarding "i have to get a token and send some requests from back"?

@GetSet
think about it, if I already have a ready-made js script, what’s the point of writing here if everything is already hacked

@electrovoz More evasion? Why not just show your code that performs the API call? Whats the secret? (Leave out the path) .... Could it be you have no idea what I mean? That you have no code that performs an API call?

im use webClient in Java,
I don’t see the point in writing the implementation of the request here, it has nothing to do with the problem

@GetSet
you are wasting our time trying to make me out to be an unscrupulous developer who decided to openly ask a question on stackoverflow, off topic

@electrovoz You show zero code on an API call. You evade easy questions that pinpoint that you have reasons to hide it or that it simply doesn't exist. The code you show is not an API call.

@electrovoz "I don’t see the point in writing the implementation of the request here" ... Makes absolutely no sense. Write what implementation? Just copy and paste the code (leave out the path).

I don’t speak English, so it’s hard for me to explain to you that, you want me to show the post method webClient??

@GetSet
added implementation,
but I deleted it because I'm afraid of getting fired

@electrovoz Anyone can view what you deleted by clicking the "edited" link beneath your post. A full history is kept of all your edits for us to look at.

If I understand it correctly, the jsrsasign code is the reference code with which the communication with the server works. What I don't understand is why you use other formats like JWE. How should the server understand this, or should the server side be adapted? Why don't you port the jsrsasign 1:1, Java on-board features are enough for this (in the case of a Java version that is too old, BouncyCastle can be applied).

And I doubt you'll get fired for it because the code itself is unremarkable and does not identify anyone.

@GetSet Oops, i very strong hacker

@Topaco
<Why don't you port jsrsasign 1:1>
I don't understand how can I do this?

@GetSet
what's wrong with you?

The jsarsasign code essentially does two things, it splits the plaintext into chunks (which is actually bad, but since it's a legacy application, this probably can't be changed), and encrypts the chunks with RSA/OAEP (with SHA384). Both can be easily implemented with Java. Regarding RSA encryption with Java, you can find many examples on SO, e.g. here.

@Topaco but I already did this using this library, in the example these lines are commented out, that’s why I asked for help on this resource, it also seems to me that this should be simple, but for some reason the modulus in js and java is different

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY... speaks for a PEM encoded key in X.509/SPKI format. If you remove the header, footer, all line breaks and Base64 decode the rest, you get an ASN.1/DER encoded key that can be imported directly with X509EncodedKeySpec.

@Topaco PemObject pemObject;
try (PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pubKey))) {
pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
}
byte[] pemBytes = pemObject.getContent();

This is ==. If you remove the header, footer, all line breaks and Base64 decode the rest,

Im trying replace(Begin/End Public Key) the result is the same

If you use a PEM reader (e.g. from BouncyCastle) you do not need to convert from PEM to DER and can import the key directly as PEM!

Incidentally, the modulus of the posted keys seems to be identical (apart from the byte order, which may be related to the internal representation of the BigInteger data type).

@Topaco
why do you think they are identical?
I thought that they start differently, these are already two different BigIntegers
395322631168.... != 58867183.....
maybe I'm not comparing correctly
 this is problem??

Load the PEM key into an ASN.1/DER parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/. On the left you will find the modulus as a decimal number, on the right hex encoded. Hex encode the first value 58867183 from the BigInteger array, 3823DEF which corresponds to the last hex digits of the hex encoded key.

I would suggest that you create an MCVE: Generate an RSA test key pair, implement the jsrsasign decryption code and test it with your jsrsasign encryption code. Port the Java encryption code (as described) and test it with the jsrsasign decryption code. In case of problems, post the test key pair, the jsrsasign decryption code and the ported Java encryption code, so that a repro is possible.

in this case, it is not clear why in js the order is random, but in java it is ordered, it needs to be parsed like in js, because it works there, does it work in this problem?

It's unlikely that the modulus is the issue. I'd expect a problem with the OAEP encryption. I'd simply not use JWE and use  "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding". Without such code there is little reason to keep debugging. Furthermore, if you're really not hacking: you're not getting enough data from the server; ask the admin for a more complete log.

@Maarten Bodewes
you may notice in the commented lines there is such an option, but it also brought the same result, to gain access to the logs you will need to go through a lot of approvals and it can take a lot of time in bureaucracy, but thanks for the idea!

As far as I understand you, the jsrsasign code is the reference code that communicates with the server. Then you actually have everything you need for porting. You just have to test the ported Java code. The easiest way to do this is with the jsrsasign decryption code (which can easily be implemented using the jsrsa encryption code).

Regarding the modulus, what do you mean by why is the order in js random? The order of the byte sequence is not random, but simply reversed. This is not unusual (and since it only affects the internal data management actually irrelevant).

@Topaco
Are you sure the byte order doesn't matter?
In this case, the whole problem lies in the encryption itself?
Directly at this point in the code -
'Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);'

What I am trying to say is that the internal data representation is actually irrelevant for you. Unless you want to derive any values from it (in which case the specifics must be taken into account). But why should you do that? Both the jsrsasign code and the Java code import the PEM key. The explicit determination of modulus and public exponentia is not necessary at all.

@Topaco
In this case, I have everything to encrypt the password, creds are not accepted due to incorrect encryption. The circle has narrowed, I will look in this direction, thank you!

And if you want to determine the modulus just for fun: In the case of jsrsasign, you can simply determine this with pubKey.n.toString(), s. here, or from the PEM encoded key with an ASN.1/DER parser, https://lapo.it/asn1js/. The values are consistent as expected. pubKey.n.toString() returns the correct value (how the data is handled internally is actually irrelevant).

unfortunately I don't have time for fun, i have deadline

I think 51 comments is strong enough evidence that the question needs more details and clarity.

Just a figure of speech! The link in my last comment should make it clear that the modulus is exported correctly despite the internally inverted data.

What I meant is that you should strip all the JWE code from your Java code as no JWE code is actually used in JS. It's just that the library also supports it and that the algorithm identifier is borrowed from it. At least, that's what it looks like to me.

I've meanwhile ported and tested the jsrsasign code to Java as described in my comment here and it works! Note that jsrsasign for RSAOAEP384 uses SHA-384 for both the OAEP and the MGF1 digest (some providers, e.g. the SunJCE provider defaults for RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding regarding the MGF1 digest to SHA-1). It is therefore more reliable if both digests are explicitly specified with OAEPParameterSpec (as in the link I posted above).

I'll try to write an answer if the post is not closed first.

@Topaco
If I understood you correctly, then all I need is to implement encryption using this tool:
Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-384ANDMGF1PADDING");
oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-384", "MGF1",
MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA384, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
and everything should work.
I'll test it tomorrow and write an answer, thank you!

OK, if you prefer to write the answer, that's fine with me. I would have implemented the JavaScript decryption code to test the Java code, but you can probably test directly against the server. Good success.

@Topaco
Hello, indeed, after explicitly specifying OAEPParameterSpec, everything worked successfully, a very unpleasant catch from Sun.
Thank you Topaco, thank you very much!
Would you like to post an answer? I think you can do it better, it would also be correct to note that the modules are the same, they are just displayed differently in java and js.

It's more the problem that the PKCS#1 specifications do not specify anything about the inner hash used for the RFC. The Java implementation chose to use a default hash (SHA-1 which is fine for the purpose), other libraries used the same hash for the data & inner hash. The latter is more sensible IMHO, but the option for choosing the hash was left open, so yeah, there will be implementation differences.

You're welcome. Agree, giving the MGF1 default digest (SHA-1) priority over identical OAEP- and MGF1-digests is not very intuitive (and a common source of OAEP issues on SO). BouncyCastle is much better here. With RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA<xxx>AndMGF1Padding both digests are specified. I put my comments as an answer.

The problem was caused by different values for the MGF1 digest: The SunJCE provider only uses SHA-384 for the OAEP digest for RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-384AndMGF1Padding, while the default SHA1 digest is applied for the MGF1 digest.
On the JavaScript side, however, for RSAOAEP384, SHA-384 is used for both digests, the OAEP and the MGF1 digest. This caused the incompatibility of both codes.
As fix, both digests must be explicitly set to SHA-384 using OAEPParameterSpec:
...
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPADDING");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-384", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA384, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParameterSpec);
...

Alternatively, the BouncyCastle provider can be used (e.g. if BouncyCastle is already being applied). This sets both the OAEP and the MGF1 digest to the specified value:
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());           
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA384AndMGF1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
...

Full code of encryptPubKeyWithPassword():
public static String encryptPubKeyWithPassword(String pubKey, String password, String version) throws Exception {       
    String encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = createRsaPublicKey(pubKey);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPADDING");
    OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-384", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA384, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParameterSpec);
    StringBuilder encryptedPasswordBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < encodedPassword.length(); i += 270) {
        String currentValue = encodedPassword.substring(i, Math.min(i + 270, encodedPassword.length()));
        if (encryptedPasswordBuilder.length() > 0) encryptedPasswordBuilder.append("00000001");
        encryptedPasswordBuilder.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(currentValue.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    }
    return encryptedPasswordBuilder.toString();
} 


Another confusion was whether the BigInteger value of the jsrsasign library contains the correct modulus (which is the case as shown in the following).
To get a reference value for the modulus, the PEM key can be loaded in an ASN.1 parser, e.g. here. Alternatively, the modulus can be determined after the key import with X509EncodedKeySpec in an RSAPublicKey instance. The modulus for the posted public PEM key is (decimal):
3953226311687758595392111994184029919105572353883850175466519164541873393823923732214781564401042342584241029257336199908139796366497541069327180034755296728788397456817216176094110417813365270437034224139108683316529614756336144052543998303152918929941819677301941145250628636498495113956820927519270970709149908767271627169825801967465740997006710347979917608611090978116377701630380908449017037401297495565187968809576663765854765455615940054260715071874403034550696249783288415681844605115585869191283022766347390049238750984142454221808268833091744962848703466396221134103055688292413446595077216756761727193028024470215530244768050010826877173235699637691655955908473771170645074319262049197935623437229535078523321083906712227132222561047274756830518955068353360103889423586339385295309120615979992652763536784371821993620190106467929309258100886903422590542463117376022420894267089887465438053796937919013636309925359

jsrsasign uses the jsbn library for BigInteger. This stores the value of a BigInteger internally in an array. The actual value is not simply the concatenation of the individual values of the array. Instead, the original value can be reconstructed as follows: The values of the array are to be hex encoded in big endian order and the hex values are to be concatenated in reverse order (109, 108,..., 1, 0):
'109': 713517      --> 0xae32d
'108': 258381146,  --> 0xf66955a
...
'1': 137037630,    --> 0x82b073e
'0': 58867183,     --> 0x3823def

This gives:
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

If this value is interpreted as an unsigned big endian hex value, the correct decimal modulus results.
However, an understanding of the internal data processing is actually not required, as imported data is automatically converted to the internal format and the BigInteger functions (toString(), toRadix(), toByteArray(),...) return the data in the correct format, as shown in the following JavaScript:


var bi = new jsbn.BigInteger('3953226311687758595392111994184029919105572353883850175466519164541873393823923732214781564401042342584241029257336199908139796366497541069327180034755296728788397456817216176094110417813365270437034224139108683316529614756336144052543998303152918929941819677301941145250628636498495113956820927519270970709149908767271627169825801967465740997006710347979917608611090978116377701630380908449017037401297495565187968809576663765854765455615940054260715071874403034550696249783288415681844605115585869191283022766347390049238750984142454221808268833091744962848703466396221134103055688292413446595077216756761727193028024470215530244768050010826877173235699637691655955908473771170645074319262049197935623437229535078523321083906712227132222561047274756830518955068353360103889423586339385295309120615979992652763536784371821993620190106467929309258100886903422590542463117376022420894267089887465438053796937919013636309925359');
console.log(bi.toRadix(16))   // hex
console.log(bi.toRadix(10))   // dec
console.log(bi.toString())    // dec
console.log(bi.toByteArray()) // signed array
console.log(bi)               // internal data representation
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbn@1.1.0/index.min.js"></script>



